# Target change a class by targeting a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is a little weird, but here's the scoop.

```
document.getElementByClassName("?").className = "Testimonialboxfull";
```

What I need to do is target a group of divs and change their class, but if I target the class it doesn't work.

Comment: because it is an HTML Collection

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName` function.  You need plural.

Comment: Please use the below link https://codepen.io/veeran/pen/NXqjEZ